# PHP get the newest saved file in a given directory

Tags: php

I have a folder saved in a specific directory and it contains some uploaded images, by the use of php how can I access to this folder using its path and return the most new added (uploaded) image in this folder?

Comment: why you are not using db+php? to keep a record of saved files with date and time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to scan the entire directory and find the latest file:

```
function getLatestFile($directoryPath) {
    $directoryPath = rtrim($directoryPath, '/');

    $max = ['path' => null, 'timestamp' => 0];

    foreach (scandir($directoryPath, SCANDIR_SORT_NONE) as $file) {
        $path = $directoryPath . '/' . $file;

        if (!is_file($path)) {
            continue;
        }

        $timestamp = filemtime($path);
        if ($timestamp > $max['timestamp']) {
            $max['path'] = $path;
            $max['timestamp'] = $timestamp;
        }
    }

    return $max['path'];
}
```

Comment: Just to say that $max should be `array('path' => null, 'timestamp' => 0);` if you don't have php 5.4. But the code works, so +1

Comment: [5.2 is not supported](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Php#Release_history) anymore.

Comment: thx could you please explain to me the line 2 ? if I will give the real path how should I change it later?

Comment: Line 2 is simply removing a trailing slash from the end if it was there. People tend to ignore the difference between `/my/path` and `/my/path/`, so this allows passing any kind of path to the function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **`filemtime()`** function:

```
<?php
// outputs e.g.  somefile.txt was last modified: December 29 2002 22:16:23.

$filename = 'somefile.txt';
if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "$filename was last modified: " . date ("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($filename));
}
?>
```

Comment: Good but she needs also a loop to check all files in that folder and get the most new one.

Comment: filename? I dont know the file name cause I have to find the last downloaded file in the folder.